# How to get the selected cell value in a DataGridView in Powershell ISE

Tags: powershell, winforms, datagridview, textbox

i have a DataGridView with columns and rows generated from a DataTable , and i have an "email" textBox  , so my question: is there a way to set the value of the email textBox to the value of the clicked email cell from the DataGridView ?

```
$dataGrid = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$dataGrid.Width = 503
$dataGrid.Height = 250
$dataGrid.location = new-object system.drawing.point(120,380)
$dataGrid.DataSource = $DataTable
$dataGrid.ReadOnly = $true

$dataGrid.RowHeadersVisible = $false
$dataGrid.AllowUserToAddRows = $false
$dataGrid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = 'Fill'


$emailMaj = New-Object Windows.Forms.TextBox
$emailMaj.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 200,300
$emailMaj.Size = New-Object Drawing.Point 130,30
```

You can see the screenshot below
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You need to set the value in the DataTable since it is the datasource.  The rows index in the DataTable and the DGV are the same.  The normal issue is the DGV doesn't automatically get repainted.  So for the update to get displayed the trick is to set the datasource to null and then back to the DGV.  So after changing the DataTable then do something like datagridview1.dataSource = $null, datagridview1.DataSource = $dt.

Comment: Hello sir, well in fact what i want is to set the value of the email textBox (the one i circled in my screenshot) automatically to the email of the cell i click with left mouse , 
for exemple if i click on the second email " vanessa...@gmail.com "  the textbox would display vanessa...@gmail.com  
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: SelectionRows is an array so you need to get first item or enumerate through the rows.  The c# code is following :             int rowIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].RowIndex;

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the hint :)

the answer is to use this :

```
$dataGrid.add_click({$val = $dataGrid.CurrentRow.Cells["email"].Value})
```

so everytime i click on a row i get the associated email !!

Thanks all .